# How to move <aside> to the left of the page

Tags: html, css

This is my first HTML page and I'm a beginner. Doing an online video HTML course.

The *aside* part which is the black part on the left does not stick entirely to the left and there's some white gap. I want to move it totally to the left.

Compare the following:

My page: https://velvety-kataifi-c1a646.netlify.app/

vs

How it supposed to look like: https://superlative-narwhal-c0f1e9.netlify.app/.

Tried playing with margins, position absolute/fixed/relative etc. but cannot get the effect as in the https://superlative-narwhal-c0f1e9.netlify.app/.

This is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>CV Alexander Marabou</title>

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <main>
        <div class="main-content">
          <h2><span class="job-title-main">Front-End Developer</span></h2>

          <h1><span class="main-name">John Doe</span></h1>

          <p class="list-primary">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
            eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Quis
            ipsum suspendisse ultrices gravida. Risus commodo viverra maecenas
            accumsan lacus vel facilisis.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="main-content-projects">
          <h2 class="header-primary">Projects</h2>
          <ol class="list-primary">
            <li>
              <a href="https://barbershop-pl.goit.global"
                >https://barbershop-pl.goit.global/</a
              >..............<span class="bold-brackets-main">[</span> HTML5,
              CSS3 <span class="bold-brackets-main">]</span>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="https://cryptohub.goit.global"
                >https://cryptohub.goit.global/</a
              ><span class="dots-lines-main">......................</span
              ><span class="bold-brackets-main"> [</span> JavaScript
              <span class="bold-brackets-main">]</span>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="https://kidslike.goit.global"
                >https://kidslike.goit.global/</a
              >..............................<span class="bold-brackets-main"
                >[</span
              >
              React.js, Node.js <span class="bold-brackets-main">]</span>
            </li>
          </ol>
        </div>
        <div class="main-content-experience">
          <h2 class="header-primary">Work Experience</h2>
          <h3 class="job-name">
            Front-End Developer <span class="orange-company">Freelance</span>
          </h3>
          <p class="year-experience">September 2019 - up to now | Country</p>
          <ul class="list-primary">
            <li>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
              eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
            </li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
            <li>Risus commodo viverra maecenas.</li>
            <li>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
              eiusmod.
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="main-content-glory-new">
          <h3>Manager <span class="orange-company">Glory New</span></h3>
          <p class="year-experience">March 2015 - October 2018 | Country</p>
          <ul class="list-primary">
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
            <li>Risus commodo viverra maecenas.</li>
            <li>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
              eiusmod.
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="main-content-glory-llc">
          <h3>Manager <span class="orange-company">Glory LLC</span></h3>
          <p class="year-experience">June 2014 - February 2015 | Country</p>
          <ul class="list-primary">
            <li>
              <span class="list-primary-item"
                >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span
              >
            </li>
            <li>
              <span class="list-primary-item"
                >Risus commodo viverra maecenas.</span
              >
            </li>
            <li>
              <span class="list-primary-item">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
                eiusmod.</span
              >
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="main-content-education">
          <h2>Education</h2>
          <h3 class="university-color">National University</h3>
          <h4 class="management-font">Management</h4>
          <p class="year-experience">September 2009 - June 2014 | Country</p>
        </div>
      </main>

      <aside>
        <img
          class="cv-photo"
          src="photo.jpg"
          width="370"
          alt="Zdjęcie Johna Doe"
        />
        <div class="contact-block">
          <h2 class="header-secondary">Contact</h2>
          <p class="contact-links">
            <span class="bold">C:</span>
            <a class="contact-links" href="tel:+7 777 777 77 77"
              >+7 777 777 77 77</a
            >
            <br />
            <span class="bold">E:</span>
            <a class="contact-links" href="mailto:johndoe@gmail.com"
              >johndoe@gmail.com</a
            >
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="tech-skills-block">
          <h2 class="header-secondary">Tech Skills</h2>
          <ul class="list-secondary">
            <li><span class="list-secondary-item">HTML5</span></li>
            <li><span class="list-secondary-item">CSS3</span></li>
            <li><span class="list-secondary-item">GIT</span></li>
            <li><span class="list-secondary-item">WebPack</span></li>
            <li><span class="list-secondary-item">JavaScript</span></li>
            <li><span class="list-secondary-item">React.js</span></li>
            <li><span class="list-secondary-item">Node.js</span></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="soft-skills-block">
          <h2 class="header-secondary">Soft Skills</h2>
          <ul class="list-secondary">
            <li><span class="list-secondary-item">Scrum</span></li>
            <li><span class="list-secondary-item">Agile</span></li>
            <li><span class="list-secondary-item">GTD</span></li>
            <li><span class="list-secondary-item">Teamwork</span></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </aside>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my CSS:

```
body {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  background: #f5f7fa;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

aside {
  width: 370px;
  background: #1e2939;
}

.cv-photo {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.header-secondary {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.contact-links {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 24px;
}
.bold {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.list-secondary {
  color: #fb6d3a;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 24px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  list-style-position: inside;
}

.list-secondary-item {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.contact-block {
  margin-top: 51px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}
.tech-skills-block {
  margin-top: 47px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}
.soft-skills-block {
  margin-top: 47px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}
.main-content {
  margin-top: 85px;
  margin-left: 88px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 247px;
  left: 498px;
  top: 125px;
}

.main-content-projects {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 88px;
  margin-bottom: 51px;
}
.main-content-experience {
  margin-top: 51px;
  margin-left: 88px;
}
.main-content-glory-new {
  margin-top: 16px;
  margin-left: 88px;
}
.main-content-glory-llc {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 88px;
}
.main-content-education {
  margin-top: 43px;
  margin-left: 88px;
  margin-bottom: 107px;
}
.year-experience {
  color: #a8a8a8;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 15px;
  margin-top: 11px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.university-color {
  color: #fb6d3a;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
.management-font {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 17px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  margin-top: 11px;
}
.list-primary {
  color: #595959;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 24px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  list-style-position: inside;
  width: 509px;
}
.list-primary-item {
  color: #595959;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 24px;
}
.header-primary {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 27px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.job-name {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
.orange-company {
  color: #fb6d3a;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
.main-name {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 45px;
  line-height: 55px;
}
.job-title-main {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 17px;
}

ol {
  margin: 0 0 1.5em;
  padding: 0;
  counter-reset: item;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  list-style-position: inside;
}

ol > li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 2em;
  text-indent: -2.7em;
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-increment: item;
  list-style-position: inside;
}

ol > li:before {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1.5em;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: right;
  content: counter(item) ".";
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.bold-brackets-main {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #000000;
}

.dots-lines-main {
  color: #a8a8a8;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends, what exactly you want. But here are the steps to move the `aside` element completely to the left:

1.) You applied a fixed `width` (1200px) to `.wrapper` which prevents the left-alignment of `aside` in larger windows. Remove that.

2.) Add `flex-grow: 1;` to `main` to allow it to fill the whole rest of the page (i.e. everything except `aside`).

3.) Add `margin: 0` to `body`to remove the default margin.

Answer (score 0):

Change the alignment of the items in the div with class `wrapper` by adding the CSS:

```
justify-content: left;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked! In the course I'm taking the guys set it to *center* and somehow worked for him: https://youtu.be/rK1pWYhsQwI?t=950 . Any idea why?

Comment: Yes.  The difference is that in the video, the .wrapper div has a width that is set to the width of <main> plus the width of <aside>.  this math results in a width that is less than what you have set in .wrapper.  Because you align the contents in the middle, that leaves the extra space on the left (but also on the right, just not as noticeable)